# Command to remove the number and revoke the MFA sessions through powershell in Azure

Tags: azure, powershell, authentication, azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

Currently doing the manual task to remove the Number of the user and then revoke multifactor authentication sessions from the portal for the off-boarding user.

is there any PowerShell command to remove the number and then revoke the MFA sessions and then save?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce in my environment using PowerShell and got the below results***

I have phone authentication method enabled for me like below:

[image]

Make sure to install the ***Microsoft.Graph.Identity.Signins*** PowerShell module like below

```
Install-module Microsoft.Graph.Identity.Signins
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes UserAuthenticationMethod.ReadWrite.All
Select-MgProfile -Name beta
```

To Remove a specific phone number for a user, use this below cmdlet

```
Remove-MgUserAuthenticationPhoneMethod -UserId user@domain.com -PhoneAuthenticationMethodId 3179e48a-750b-4051-897c-87b9720928f7
```

[image]

The value of  `id`  should be  `3179e48a-750b-4051-897c-87b9720928f7` to delete for ***mobile phone*** type

After running the above command phone number removed successfully like below

[image]

To revoke MFA session, use the below [cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/revoke-azureaduserallrefreshtoken?view=azureadps-2.0)

```
Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken -ObjectId "xxxxxxx"
```

[image]

***Reference***: [Manage authentication methods for Azure AD Multi-Factor Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-userdevicesettings)